# Invalid conversion from throwing function to non-throwing function

Tags: swift, moya

- xcode: Version 10.0 (10A255)
- swift: 4.2
- Moya: 4.5

I try to make `NetworkManager` struct.

```
struct NetworkManager: Networkable {

    internal var provider = MoyaProvider<VideoAPI>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure, requestClosure: requestClosure, plugins: [networkPlugin], trackInflights: false)
    static let environment: APIEnvironment = .development

    func recentlyList(page: Int, completion: @escaping (String) -> (Void)) {
        provider.request(.recentlyList(params: ["page": page])) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case let .success(response):
                do {
                    let jsonData = try JSON(data: response.data)
                    print(jsonData)

                    completion(String(data: response.data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            case let .failure(error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

How can i fix this issue?

I learn this code from [here](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/getting-started-with-moya-f559c406e990)

--------------------update

Edit Podfile, change Moya to `pod 'Moya', git: 'https://github.com/Moya/Moya.git', branch: 'development'`

run `pod install` in terminal, It's working.

Comment: Your do block needs a catch block.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Always post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (not images) so they are searchable, and can be copied when answering. Please [edit] your question

Comment: It's great that you solved this, but the way to indicate that, believe it or not, is to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `catch` in your code which means that your are not catching the parsing errors, making your closure *throwing*.

Adding `catch` should fix the problem:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSON(data: response.data)
    print(jsonData)

    completion(String(data: response.data, endcoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
} catch { 
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Same error? Please add the updated code to your question.

Comment: I updated Podfile, change Moya to git source, branch is development, it's working. thanks.